# Passing :locals argument to partial rendered by link_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the documentation for [link_to_remote](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001613)

> The result of that request can then be inserted into a DOM object whose id can be specified with options[:update].  Usually, the result would be a partial prepared by the controller with render :partial.

For example, one would do this:

```
<%= link_to_remote( "Some link text", :url => url, :method => method, :update => 'name_of_partial' %>
```

Is there a way to pass a :locals hash to the partial (in the example above, 'name_of_partial') similar to when you would render it using "render :partial"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't quite understand.  The `:update` argument is the html `id` of the element that will have its contents replaced by the contents of the result of this ajax call.

```
<div id="ajax_message"></div>
<%= link_to_remote 'click me',
                   :url => my_ajax_action_path,
                   :update => 'ajax_message' %>
```

The partial in question is rendered in response to the ajax request in your controller.

```
def my_ajax_action
  @my_object = MyOobject.find(params[:id]) #or something
  render :partial => 'my_object',
         :locals => { :my_object => @my_object }
end
```

The resulting response body is then shoved into your previously named element via the `:update` argument.